# How to align the Navigation Title the left when using large Titles?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, alignment, nsattributedstring

When large Titles are enabled, the Heading of the View is always centered when the Title is in the "small" state. How do I change that?

I can't set a custom UILabel as the titleView because the large title would be affected as well with this approach.

So I tried this:

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .left
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.black,
                  NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle:paragraph]
self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

But this, unfortunately, does not affect the alignment of the title in its small state at all. (Color change works)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506238/how-do-i-left-align-the-title-of-a-navigation-bar-in-xcode

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Your linked question has nothing to do with large titles.

Answer (score -3):

Inside view did load, create a UILabel with desired attributes.
then set teh navigation left bar button item like this

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myLabel)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the "button" is also there when the large Title is active.