# How to remove space that is created by prefersLargeTitles = true in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, uinavigationbar

How to remove the additional space that is created when you set `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`?

I understand it is navigationBar itself, but is it possible to make that largeTitle upper (right under the status bar) than its initial position which is slightly lower?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49454513/9496051) seems to be even better solution for the problem.

**Initial Answer:**

Not really, it is not possible to achieve without some excessive hacking which eventually will could cause problems.

What you could do is to try to set `titleView` on navigation bar and set width constraint equal to the navigation bar width. Try with a simple `UILabel`, and set `prefersLargeTitles = false` and do not use `navigationItem.title` for this screen.

[Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44932834/8160613)

Note that since you are not using default titles you will lose some features like collapsing the title to smaller one when scrolling a list in this screen.

Comment: The workaround of creating a UILabel and setting it as `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` worked pretty well, and no constraints were set in my case.
Note: I didn't need no back button in the specific controller nor the collapsing feature.

Comment: You may add this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49454513/9496051 to your answer or just the solution with `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`, I will mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

For me the only working solution is:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
}
```

in

```
viewWillAppear()
```